# Shift rows in pandas dataframe in a specific order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, shift

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'job': ['football','football', 'football', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'football','football', 'football', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'hokey'],
     'team': [4.0,5.0,9.0,2.0,3.0,6.0,1.0,7.0,8.0, 4.0,5.0,9.0,2.0,3.0,6.0,1.0,7.0,8.0],
     'cluster': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
     })
```

[image]

Each `cluster` contains 9 teams. Each cluster has 3 teams of each type of sport `football`, `basketball` and `hokey`. I want to apply a shift-function to each cluster, so that the order of teams chance in a very specific way (I tried to highlight it with color):

[image]

How can I do this transformation (shift rows in a way shown above) for a much larger dataframe?

Comment: Please explain what is your criteria of sorting

Comment: I tried to explain it above. For each cluster: take first team ``football``, ``basketball`` and ``hockey``, respectively. Then take second team ``football``, ``basketball`` and ``hockey``, respectively.  Then take third team ``football``, ``basketball`` and ``hockey``, respectively. Hope you can see the pattern in my figures

Comment: I now understand. Let me think of a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do `groupby` + `cumcount` to create a sequential counter based on the columns `cluster` and `job` then use `sort_values` to sort the dataframe on `cluster` and this `counter`:

```
df['j'] = df.groupby(['cluster', 'job']).cumcount()
df = df.sort_values(['cluster', 'j'], ignore_index=True).drop('j', axis=1)
```

---

```
           job  team  cluster
0     football   4.0        0
1   basketball   2.0        0
2        hokey   1.0        0
3     football   5.0        0
4   basketball   3.0        0
5        hokey   7.0        0
6     football   9.0        0
7   basketball   6.0        0
8        hokey   8.0        0
9     football   4.0        1
10  basketball   2.0        1
11       hokey   1.0        1
12    football   5.0        1
13  basketball   3.0        1
14       hokey   7.0        1
15    football   9.0        1
16  basketball   6.0        1
17       hokey   8.0        1
```

Comment: @PParker Happy coding!