# New column in pandas dataframe with values which increase stepwise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'job': ['football','football', 'football', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'football','football', 'football', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'hokey'],
     'team': [4.0,5.0,9.0,2.0,3.0,6.0,1.0,7.0,8.0, 4.0,5.0,9.0,2.0,3.0,6.0,1.0,7.0,8.0],
     'cluster': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
     })
```

[image]

How can I add a new column `position` which stepwise increases in value.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Similar yes, but not the same, right? Maybe you can enlighten me?

Comment: I think you can use the [`answer from your previous question`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64194946/12833166) then add the extra line `df['position'] = df.groupby('job').cumcount().add(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
 'job': ['football','football', 'football', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'football','football', 'football', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'hokey', 'hokey', 'hokey'],
 'team': [4.0,5.0,9.0,2.0,3.0,6.0,1.0,7.0,8.0, 4.0,5.0,9.0,2.0,3.0,6.0,1.0,7.0,8.0],
 'cluster': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
 })
    po=[(x//3)+1 for x in range(len(df)) ]

    df["position"]=po
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution is simple and I was thinking to complex!